# Inserta 4 letras al inicio del vector

Tags: c++

Tengo que insertar 4 letras al inicio del vector

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i;
    char c='a';
    vector <char> caracter(10);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        caracter[i]=c;
        c++;
    }
    cout<<"letras del alfabeto"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<caracter[i]<<"-"; 
    }
    cout<<" "<<endl;
    //v.push_front(T)   segun un folleto que nos dio el profe sirve para insertar un elemento al principio del vector
    caracter.push_front(T);//no se como utilizarlo 
/*  for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        caracter[i]='c';
    }*/
    cout<<"4 letras c insertadas al inicio"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        cout<<caracter[i]<<"-"; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`vector`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) no tiene utilidad para insertar al inicio. ¿Estás seguro que tiene que ser un `vector` y no una lista?

Comment: si dice que utilizemos el contenedor vector

Comment: Entonces tienes que crear un segundo `vector` con los 4 elementos que quieres insertar y luego copiar al final de este nuevo `vector` los elementos del `vector` original.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (con la que deberías empezar a familiarizarte) la clave `vector` no dispone de ningún método llamado `push_front`.

Sin embargo, la documentación de la clase [`list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) indica que dicho contenedor sí que contiene dicho método.

El funcionamiento es muy simple. `list` representa una lista doblemente enlazada y `push_front` inserta un elemento al inicio de la lista:

```
std::list<char> items;
items.push_front('a');
items.push_front('b');

// En este punto la lista contiene B -> A
```

Ahora bien, si el problema tienes que solucionarlo con `vector` la cosa se complica ligeramente porque, como hemos visto, `vector` no posee dicho método.

Puedes optar por añadir los elementos uno a uno usando el método `insert`:

```
std::vector<char> lista;

// Para rellenar la lista
lista.push_back('a');
lista.push_back('b');
lista_push_back('c');

// Nuevo elemento al inicio
lista.insert(lista.begin(),'c'); // esto 4 veces

for( size_t i=0; i<lista.size(); i++ )
  std::cout << lista[i];
```

O bien puedes crear un segundo vector y añadir su contenido al inicio de tu lista:

```
std::vector<char> lista;

// Para rellenar la lista
lista.push_back('a');
lista.push_back('b');
lista_push_back('c');

// Nuevo contenedor
std::vector<char> nuevos(4,'c'); // Crea cuatro elementos con valor 'c'

// Nuevo elemento al inicio
lista.insert(lista.begin(),nuevos.begin(),nuevos.end());

for( size_t i=0; i<lista.size(); i++ )
  std::cout << lista[i];
```

Comment: muchas gracias comenzare a probar tus soluciones